# ModSecurity runtime rule exclusion failing with error "ModSecurity: Missing target for id"

Tags: apache2, mod-security

I read [Folini's great tutorial for ModSecurity with Apache](https://www.netnea.com/cms/apache-tutorials/).

I am trying to set a [*runtime exclusion rule*](https://www.netnea.com/cms/apache-tutorial-7_including-modsecurity-core-rules/#step_7_handling_false_positives_disabling_individual_rules), that should disable rule 920420 (*Request content type is not allowed by policy*) but only for requests to a certain subdir, es

- `/path/to/allow/`
- `/path/to/allow/one`
- `/path/to/allow/two`

So I came up with this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@beginsWith /path/to/allow/" "phase:1,nolog,pass,id:10001,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=920420"
```

but it's not working, on the apache error_log I still see

```
[Thu Oct 19 08:56:20.210636 2023] [:error] [pid 1024043:tid 140057339950848] [client x.x.x.x:0] [client x.x.x.x] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "within %{tx.allowed_request_content_type}" against "TX:content_type" required. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "957"] [id "920420"] [msg "Request content type is not allowed by policy"] [data "|application/csp-report|"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.4"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/255/153"] [tag "PCI/12.1"] [hostname "xxx.xxx.xxx"] [uri "/path/to/allow/one"] [unique_id "ZTDTFFJD7si4Et@hbb2tdwAAANc"]
```

preceded by this log entry, reporting *Missing target for id "920420"* that seems an internal ModSecurity error, but I can't find anything online about this error

```
[Thu Oct 19 08:56:20.207372 2023] [:error] [pid 982022:tid 140057348343552] [client x.x.x.x:0] [client x.x.x.x] ModSecurity: ModSecurity: Missing target for id "920420" [hostname "xxx.xxx.xxx"] [uri "/path/to/allow/one"] [unique_id "ZTDTFJGGmUw09aDzrMRLvQAAABY"]
```

Why my rule exclusion is not working?